# async function still freezing UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function called on a submit form

```js
 async solve(e){
        
        const waiter = (args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this.CalculateValues(args))
          })
        e.preventDefault();
        let V=this.state.fields;
        let B =await waiter(V);
            this.setState({
                BrokerFees:B,
                SolveState:"Solve",
            });
  
    }
```

as you can see in the code I have a function that returns Promise i am using await keyword inside async function still my UI freezes.
Please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: How do you call `solve`?

Comment: What does `this.CalculateValues` do?  If it's a blocking operation then it's going to block the UI.  Promises are not separate threads.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use `async` here :

```
solve(e){
        
        const waiter = async (args) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this.CalculateValues(args))
          })
        e.preventDefault();
        let V=this.state.fields;
        let B =await waiter(V);
            this.setState({
                BrokerFees:B,
                SolveState:"Solve",
            });
  
    }
```

Comment: By doing this get a syntax error cannot use await keyword outside an async function
I added async to solve too but still UI freezes

Comment: @Mohcine Not at all. You are adding the `async` keyword for no reason. Not using `await` inside the function makes it useless. Also you removed the `async` keyword from the main function, which uses `await`, so it must be marked as `async`. This code will never even compile.